# How to negate RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.1.0/24'" in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4

I cannot figure out how to negate a rewritecond that matches client IP:

`RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.1.0/24'"`

Let's say that I want to match if the remote ip address is **not** this one. What's the syntax?

I read [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) but didn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Found it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024233/1204976)

```
RewriteCond expr "! -R '12.345.678.90/28'"
```